# Copying the props of an object into another one with different values with some adaptions

Tags: javascript

I do appreciate your support with the following:

I am trying to create a function with which i could create new elements. The `elementsFactory` function has a parameter for the passed options which will be added as attributes. Inside the function there are two objects, one for default options and other empty one for the passed options.

What i want to do:

1. Copying the props of the default options into the options object if its empty.
2. To be able to edit the values of the options object without problems.
3. If there is a property in the default options which hasn't been passed into the options object, i want the options object to copy it with its value.

What I can not do:

The last `else if` statement lets me copy the rest of props in the default options which have not been passed into the options object, but it makes the values somehow not configurable.

The settings function does not work at all.

Here is my JS Code:

```
function elemFactory(tag, parent, id, idVal) {
    prop = [];
    var el = document.createElement(tag);
    //var className= document.getElementsByClassName(class);
    var parent = document.getElementById(parent);
    parent.appendChild(el);
    el.setAttribute(id, idVal);

    return el;
}
var options = {};
function createTheElement(options) {
    var box = elemFactory("div", "test", "id", "bonbon-div");
    var defaultOptions = {
        visiabilty: true,
        width: "100px",
        color: "blue",
        height: "30px",
        class: "bonbon-box-propation"

    };

    function setOptions() {
        for (var i in defaultOptions) {

            if (defaultOptions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                for (var option in options) {
                    if (option === i && options[option] === defaultOptions[i]) {
                        box.setAttribute(option, defaultOptions[option]);
                    } else if (option === i && options[option] !== defaultOptions[i]) {
                        box.setAttribute(option, options[option]);

                    } else if (option !== i) {
                        box.setAttribute(i, defaultOptions[i]);
                    }

                    (function settings() {
                        if (options.visiabilty) {
                            console.log(options.visiabilty);
                            if (options.visiabilty === true) {
                                box.style.display = "block";
                            } else {
                                box.style.display = "none";

                            }
                        }

                    })();

                }
            }
        }
    }
    setOptions();

}

createTheElement({
    visiabilty: false,
    width: "200px",
    color: "black",
    height: "40px"
});
```

I am really sorry if my code looks bit messy, I just started JS and web development 6 months ago. I am looking forward to your solutions.

Comment: What is the error say that is occurring from the problem? It would help if we get some context on the error message.

Comment: By the way, ```if (options.visiabilty)``` and ```if (options.visiabilty === true) {``` are the same thing. You can just do ```if (options.visiability) { //code } else { //code }``` it will work the same way (That might also be why your settings function is not working. The "else" block is not being reached if options.visiability is false in the beginning)

Comment: Hello Chris,
many thanks, the settings function has worked.

Comment: i don't get any errors to work around this.

Comment: i changed the last "else if" statement with the following and it worked: else if(!options.hasOwnProperty(i)){
  box.setAttribute(i, defaultOptions[i]);
 }